# a man like Lincoln

Tags: clauses

Can one say

> Robots, like human beings, were moving towards us.

instead of "*Robots, **which were** like human beings, were moving towards us.*"?

and

> A tall man, like Lincoln, was waiting at the gate.

instead of "*A tall man, **who was** like Lincoln, was waiting at the gate.*"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a specific rule on it, but to my ears, your phrases seem to mean something more like this:

> Robots were moving towards us, like human beings move towards us.
>
> A tall man was waiting at the gate, like Lincoln was waiting at the gate.

In both cases, it reads as if you're describing the subject performing and action in a manner similar to another person or object or as we expect that other person or object to, rather than comparing your subject to that other person or object. So compare to the sentence:

> "Dogs, like cats, eat meat"

We're not saying dogs look like cats, we're saying that they perform similar actions (eating meat).

A more natural phrasing for your sentences might be:

> Human-like robots were moving towards us.
>
> A man, tall like Lincoln, was waiting at the gate.

In the second phrase, the structure is similar to yours, but moving the adjective into the comparison makes it clear that you're comparing the heights and not the action of waiting at the gate.